# Mostrar Registros pero no mostrar Registros repetidos

Tags: php, sql, filtro

**RESUMEN**

Me gustaría que por medio un Query me muestre registros de una columna en especifico pero NO me muestre los Registros Repetidos aqui esta la Query que muestra que columna en especifico quiero mostrar:

```
SELECT Sexo FROM Persona;
```

**Resultado**

|Sexo|

M

F

M

F

F

F

M

**Problema**

Pero quiero que me haga un filtro y solo me muestre los registros que se tienen

**Ejemplo**

|Sexo|

M

F

**USO PHP Y SQL SERVER**

Comment: Kevins, ya llevas quince días en el sitio, te invito a leer [Cómo realizar una buena pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). También te invito a crear un [ejemplo mínimo completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) para que podamos ayudarte de una mejor manera. Por el momento puedes decirnos qué has intentado?

Comment: Cuál es el motor de bases de datos que estás ocupando? La etiqueta `sql` se refiere únicamente al lenguaje. La solución para `SqlServer` puede ser diferente a la de `MySql`, o `PosgreSQL`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

puedes hacerlo con la clausula [DISTINCT](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-mx/sql/dmx/select-distinct-from-model-dmx?view=sql-server-ver15) :

## ejemplo

```
SELECT DISTINCT Sexo FROM Persona;
```

Comment: Gracias Si me funciono !!!